# Why is array declaration missing when the file is uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, server

The application is working fine locally, but when the file is uploaded to the server, it's throwing "Uncaught ReferenceError: avatarList is not defined at changeImage". On looking at the source code in the browser, the array declaration is missing even though I have declared. I have uploaded the same file as that of the local.

```html
function changeImage(buffer){
    var avatarList =["./images/avatar/1.png","./images/avatar/2.png","./images/avatar/3.png","./images/avatar/4.png","./images/avatar/5.png","./images/avatar/6.png"]; 
    buffer.src=avatarList[(generateRandom(avatarList.length)-1)]
    return buffer;
}
```

This is the snapshot of the [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7D7H.jpg) and the [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB9dT.jpg) from the browser.

Comment: Please add code to the question. Avoid images!

Comment: Have added the source code.

Comment: What is the server you are talking about here?

Comment: I have uploaded to infinityfree.net hosting provider.

Comment: It's either an error in your source code, a problem with the way you're uploading the code, or a problem with the hosting provider. Try a different hosting provider? And are you sure the file you're uploading has the `var avatarList = ...` line in it?